# Java application connectivity issue for Oracle8 Release 8.0.5.0.0

Tags: java, database, oracle

I've given a task to connect to Oracle8 Release 8.0.5.0.0 from a Java application. My code snippet is as follows.

```
import java.sql.*;

class OracleConOldJava {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Connection con = null;
        Statement stmt = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;

        try {
            // Load the Oracle JDBC driver
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");

            // Establish the database connection
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(
                "jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168.1.3:1521/DBNAME", "USERNAME", "PASSWORD");

            // Create a statement
            stmt = con.createStatement();

            // Execute the SQL query with FETCH FIRST to limit the number of rows
            rs = stmt.executeQuery(
                "SELECT COL1, COL2, COL3 FROM TABLE_A FETCH FIRST 5 ROWS ONLY");

            // Iterate through the result set and print the data
            while (rs.next()) {
                System.out.println(
                    rs.getInt("COL") + "  " +
                    rs.getString("COL2") + "  " +
                    rs.getString("COL3"));
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                // Close the resources in the reverse order of acquisition
                if (rs != null) rs.close();
                if (stmt != null) stmt.close();
                if (con != null) con.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm using ojdbc14.jar with java 1.4.

When I run the code getting below error.

```
C:\j2sdk1.4.2_18\bin\java.exe -cp .;ojdbc14.jar OracleConOldJava
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 1
ORA-02248: invalid option for ALTER SESSION

        at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:112)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:331)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:283)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:278)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoauthenticate.receiveOauth(T4CTTIoauthenticate.java:785)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:362)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:414)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:165)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:35)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:801)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:512)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:171)
        at OracleConOldJava.main(OracleConOldJava.java:14)
```

I've used java 1.8 with ojdbc8.jar and java 1.4 with ojdbc14.jar. Same error occurred.
What could be the reason for this? Is it due to driver mismatch? If so what is the driver I have to use?

Comment: `FETCH FIRST 5 ROWS ONLY` is supported in Oracle 12c and above.  Try to remove it. See https://www.dbi-services.com/blog/oracle-rownum-vs-rownumber-and-12c-fetch-first/

Comment: You are running a version of Java that was EOL in 2008 to connect to an Oracle database that was EOL before 2003.  And you are using an application that is using Oracle SQL features introduced in 2013.  Are you seeing the problem here?

Comment: I've changed the select statement. Still, the issue persists. modified query is "SELECT COL1,COL2,COL3 FROM SCHEMA_A.TABLE_A WHERE COL1=1".

Comment: The error is occurred at "con = DriverManager.getConnection(
                "jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168.1.3:1521/DBNAME", "USERNAME", "PASSWORD");" This is why suspect something to do with ojdbc version and java version

Answer (score 0):

You have (at least) two problems:

1. The error message is:

   ```
   ORA-02248: invalid option for ALTER SESSION
   ```

   This means that, when you create the connection and Oracle implicitly starts a session, an `ALTER SESSION` command is being invoked and that command is invalid. You do not show any `ALTER SESSION` commands so it is probably in a trigger. You need to fix that command so it is valid.
2. The `FETCH FIRST n ROWS ONLY` syntax was introduced in Oracle 12. You are using Oracle 8 so it is not going to work. Instead, you want:

   ```sql
   SELECT COL1, COL2, COL3 FROM TABLE_A WHERE ROWNUM <= 5
   ```

   However, you probably want an `ORDER BY` clause as well (otherwise you are getting 5 random rows, rather than 5 specific rows).

   ```sql
   SELECT * FROM (SELECT COL1, COL2, COL3 FROM TABLE_A ORDER BY COL1, COL2, COL2) WHERE ROWNUM <= 5
   ```

Comment: I've changed the select statement. But error is same. The error is giving at "con = DriverManager.getConnection(
                "jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168.1.3:1521/DBNAME", "USERNAME", "PASSWORD");". Therefore, isn't the issue with connectivity?

Comment: @NuwanMadushanka See issue #1 in the answer. You need to work out where the `ALTER SESSION` command is being invoked and fix it. (As mentioned in the answer, there is probably a trigger that fires on logon; you can talk to your DBA and ask what logon triggers there are.)

Answer (score 0):

Managed to fix with Java 1.2 and classes12.zip

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).